# Getting metadata in plain SQL statement in Slick 3.1.x

Tags: slick, slick-3.0

In the following plain SQL statement in Slick I know beforehand that it will return a list of (String, String)

```
sql"""select c.name, s.name
      from coffees c, suppliers s
      where c.price < $price and s.id = c.sup_id""".as[(String, String)]
```

But what if I don't know the column types? Can I analyze the metadata and retrieve the values? In JDBC I could use getInt(n) and getString(n), is there anything similar in Slick?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tsql` (Type-Checked SQL Statements)](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/sql.html#type-checked-sql-statements):

```
tsql"""select c.name, s.name
      from coffees c, suppliers s
      where c.price < $price and s.id = c.sup_id"""
```

this will return a `DBIO[Seq[(String, String)]]` (depending on the column types).

> produces a `DBIOAction` of the correct type without requiring a call to `.as`

*Note: I've found it a little flakey (to the point of being unusable) with option types, so beware if your columns can be `null` (since `null: String`).*

This requires a little bit of wiring up, you need [`@StaticDatabaseConfig`](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/api/index.html#slick.backend.StaticDatabaseConfig) (e.g. on your DAO), as these types are checked, against the database, at compile time:

```
# annotate the object
@StaticDatabaseConfig("file:src/main/resources/application.conf#tsql")
...

    val dc = DatabaseConfig.forAnnotation[JdbcProfile]
    import dc.driver.api._
    val db = dc.db

    # to pull out a Future[Seq[String, String]]
    # use db.run(tsql"...")
    # to pull out a Future[Option[(String, String)]]
    # use db.run(tsql"...".headOption)
    # etc.
```